# How can I underflow a number in constant time O(1)?

Tags: java, integer-overflow

I want to create a "datatype", that does an underflow in constant time.
So if you have `10` as an upper bound, and pass the value `12`, it gives you `8`.

In the following code, `max` is the upper entry bound for my value `val`.

```
while(val > max)
   val -= max;
```

Currently I have only this iterative code, which could be expressed with a modulo-operation. I just don't know how.

Example for `6`
[image]

Comment: That doesn't really work like expected. It should end up with (n=10 : 4, n=11 : 3, n=12 : 2, n = 15 : 6).
Your solution produces 0 for 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with `val = val % max` ? (If anything, please show more counterexamples.)

UPDATE: assuming the *Bound* in image is the same thing as `max` variable it seems you want expression `max - (val - 1) % (max + 1)`.

Comment: @xtay2 updated answer

Comment: Nevermind I had a typo, thx

Comment: @xtay2 unit test with expected output would be better specification (rather than imgur image) for such kind of tasks

Comment: n = 0 produces bounds + 1 btw. But I can build an edgecase for that.